# pure data [hist] implementation

Tags: puredata

No idea how to use `[hist]` in Pure Data. 
And the three arguments of `[hist]` is:

- the value of first class,
- the value of last class,
- the number of classes.

I cannot figure out the first and second argument meaning? And how am I going to pass the output of `[hist]` to `[tabwrite]` and generate an array diagram in Pure Data.

Comment: there is no `hist` object in Pd (vanilla); where does it come from (which library)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the `[hist]` object from *smlib*.

The histogram will contain `<number of classes>` bins of equal size, with the first bin being equivalent to the `<value of first class>` and the last bin being equivalent to `<value of last class>-1` (the offset is arguably a bug).

So, the *value of first class* is the minimum expected input value (`x>=min`), and the *value of last class* is the maximum expected input value (`x<<max`).
Any input value exceeding those boundaries will be clipped.

#### Examples:

```
[3, absolute(
|
[hist 2 5 3]
|
[print]
```

This will create a 3-bin histogram, with the bins `2±0.5` (with clipping this means `x<2.5`), `3±0.5` and `4±0.5` (with clipping that is `3.5<x`).
The input `3` will be filed into the second bin, so the `absolute` histogram is `0 1 0`.

Similarily:

```
[3, absolute(
|
[hist 3 6 3]
|
[print]
```

This will create a 3-bin histogram, with the bins `3±0.5`, `4±0.5` and `5±0.5`.
The input `3` will be now filed into the first bin, so the `absolute` histogram is `1 0 0`.

#### Displaying the histogram:

You can set the table-values by sending a list of number to the table, prefixed with the starting index:

```
[relative(
|
[hist 0 100 100]
|
[list prepend 0]
|
[s $0-histo]

[table $0-histo 100]
```

Alternatively check the `[array]` object (which also can be accessed via `[tabread]` and the like)